# Get last ID and display it

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-insert-id

I've been looking around but most of the tutorials are showing the `mysql_insert_id()` but it's on the same document. I'm wondering if there is a way where you can get the last id of a column and echo it out.

```
$image = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE id=$id");
$image = mysql_fetch_assoc($image) or die(mysql_error());

$image = $image['image'];

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

echo $image;
```

This is my code that gets the image from the database and makes the blob into a id?=1 which is the picture but as php. That is a uploader from another php document but I'm typing to output the last id from that column on another page (Not the picture but the number for statistics)

A bit of code that could do that would be very helpful.

Comment: On a side note, I really suggest you stop using the old mysql library and switch to PDO or at least mysqli for php.  You want to use a prepared statement for the $id in the where clause to protect against injection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would grab the row with the highest `ID`:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(id) FROM images");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
// $row[0] contains the value of the highest id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: `select max(id) from images` is far easier and lest wasteful.

Comment: @MarcB - Sorry, you are right.  I misunderstood the post.  I thought they were saying they were getting the image out of the db.  max(id) is ABSOLUTELY the way to go.  Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

Immediately after the query is done, use:

```
$newId = mysql_insert_id();
```

It will return the last inserted id

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECt MAX(id) FROM images";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_affected_rows($result);

echo $row[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

With PDO [How to return max(id) in pdo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29332891/how-to-return-maxid-in-pdo)

```
$sql_lastid = $pdo -> prepare("SELECT MAX(id) as max_id FROM *table*");
$sql_lastid -> execute();
$id     = $sql_lastid -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$lastid = $id['max_id'];
```