# How to return max(id) in pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to return the last id and increment it to put in the value attribute. I can make it work with old mysql but not with the PDO. I am learning (I think) PDO but it is not making sense.

Below is the code.

```html
    <td><label for="invNum"></label>Invoice</td>
    <?php
    $stmt = $dbconn->prepare("SELECT max(invId) FROM     invoices");
    $stmt->execute();
    $invNum = $stmt->fetch();
    
    /* mysql_select_db("customers", $dbconn);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT max(invId) FROM   invoices");
    if (!$result) {
    die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
    }
    $invNum = mysql_result($result, 0);*/
    ?>
    <td><input type="text" name="invNum" id="invNum" 
    size="12" value="<?php echo ++$invNum; ?>" /></td>
```

Comment: Why don't you use `::lastInsertId()`? http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: Simply assuming that you can take the last ID and add one to it only works if nobody else ever uses your system.... the moment you have a second user is the moment it breaks

Comment: You should have an auto-incremented column and then use `lastInsertId()` if you need the value.

Comment: I'm just trying to build a Invoice template for personal use and education. So nobody else will be using it.  I don't understand the  php manual instructions. Thank you Pat

Comment: So the question is really about prepare+execute+fetch.  What do you get in `$invNum`?  Do you have any error messages?

Answer (score 5):

Try this :

```
  $stmt = $dbconn->prepare("SELECT MAX(invId) AS max_id FROM invoices");
  $stmt -> execute();
  $invNum = $stmt -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $max_id = $invNum['max_id'];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enter a new line right away:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databasename','username','password');

$statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO invoices(data1, data2, data3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$statement->execute(array('bla', 'bla', 'bla'));   

$newID = $pdo->lastInsertId();
```